# PropertyInfo SetValue and nulls

Tags: c#, reflection, default

If I have something like:

```
object value = null;
Foo foo = new Foo();

PropertyInfo property = Foo.GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "IntProperty");
property.SetValue(foo, value, null);
```

Then `foo.IntProperty` gets set to `0`, even though `value = null`.  It appears it's doing something like `IntProperty = default(typeof(int))`.  I would like to throw an `InvalidCastException` if `IntProperty` is not a "nullable" type (`Nullable<>` or reference).  I'm using Reflection, so I don't know the type ahead of time.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have the `PropertyInfo`, you can check the `.PropertyType`; if `.IsValueType` is true, and if `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType)` is null, then it is a non-nullable value-type:

```
        if (value == null && property.PropertyType.IsValueType &&
            Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException ();
        }
```

Comment: That's it.  I was messing with .PropertyType.IsClass, but wasn't getting very far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()) expression to determine whether specified value can be written into property. But you need to handle case when value is null, so in this case you can assign it to property only if property type is nullable or property type is reference type:

```
public bool CanAssignValueToProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) != null ||
               !propertyInfo.IsValueType;
    else
        return propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());
}
```

Also, you may find useful Convert.ChangeType method to write convertible values to property.

Comment: SetValue() already throws an exception when it can't set the value, which is desired behavior (but it's an ArgumentException).  I only need to handle the null scenario.