# Shouldn't using FieldInfo.SetValue to set a ValueType to null fail?

Tags: .net, clr, least-astonishment

(related to [PropertyInfo SetValue and nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049477/propertyinfo-setvalue-and-nulls))

If I have `public class Thing { public int X; }`, a `Thing o`, and a `FieldInfo fi` that points to the `X` field, why is it legal to call `fi.SetValue(o, null)`? The runtime sets the field `X` to zero, i.e. `default(int)` instead of complaining that a `ValueType` cannot be set to `null`.

Does anyone know the design choice behind this behavior, which at least from C# violates my principle of least astonishment?

Comment: I agree, it should throw an ArgumentException, according to the docs at least.

Comment: This is frustrating behavior for the Reflection API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text contained in the Exceptions box for `ArgumentException` suggests that the value passed in is subject to *conversion*, which would explain why it succeeds.

> The value parameter cannot be converted and stored in the field.

I do agree that it seems slightly strange, particularly as I generally expect the reflection APIs to be one of the more rigid and less forgiving.

You might try contacting [Eric Lippert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/) , whilst this is a BCL/CLR question rather than C#, there's a chance he'll know the answer or know someone who does. Either that or be able to give a very good guess.